# Is there any documentation for @types/express?

Tags: typescript, express

I learned from a book I can type express with TypeScript like this:

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
const app = express();
app.use((err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
});
```

I am still not clear how everybody reached out this code. I am sure express declaration file exports these types (Request, Response, NextFunction), but I cannot be convinced it is correct type.

I also couldn't find any @types/express documentation.

How do TypeScript engineer find out the way to type for each library?

Comment: A package under the `@types` namespace **is** documentation :-) Use `npm install -D @types/express` and enjoy your VSCode helping you to write code using Express.

Comment: the types are community driven see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts its not uncommon for types to become out of date and not match the actual library's behavior.